# Render and encapsulate Preact into an iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, preact

I am trying to create an **iframe** containing Preact that can be implemented into different frameworks. The iframe being able to communicate with the parent window over events. The package needs to be importable by npm, I think. ESM is also an alternative, but I do not understand how that can be done during development. I have tried using a **custom element** but that does not encapsulate javascript and leads to hooks errors when rendering **Preact inside React**.

The following steps that I thought were possible:
1. Create my-fun-app. Exports an es module using microbundle.

```
import { h, render } from 'preact'
import App from './containers/app'
import { EventBus } from './utilities/bus'

let container
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  container = document.querySelector('.container')
  window.parent.EventBus = new EventBus()
}
render(h(App), document.querySelector('.container'))

export const start = (rootElement, target) => {
  render(h(App), document.querySelector('.container'))
  // render(h(App), rootElement, target)
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.parent.EventBus = new EventBus()
  }
}
```

2. Nextjs the imports my-fun-app

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
// import 'my-fun-app'

const getBlobURL = (code, type) => {
  const blob = new Blob([code], { type })
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
}

const MyFunApp = () => {
  const refContainer = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let container = document.createElement('div')
    container.id = 'container'
    refContainer.current.contentDocument.body.appendChild(container)
    let moduleScript = document.createElement('script')
    moduleScript.type = 'module'
    const jsURL = getBlobURL(require('my-fun-app', 'text/javascript')
    moduleScript.src = jsURL
    refContainer.current.contentDocument.head.appendChild(moduleScript)
  }, [])

  return (
    <iframe
      ref={refContainer}
      id="my-iframe"
    ></iframe>
  )
}
```

Tried rendering Preact with

```
render(<App />, getQuerySelector('#my-iframe').contentWindow.document.body)
```

and that renders the app into the iframe, but it does not encapsulate it. As an example if react-hook-form is imported into my-fun-app there arrises some kind of circular dependency leading to a hooks error.

I am slowly getting to the point thinking that it is not possible, but almost everything is possible. Hope that you can help with some guidance.